# how to create a function return as Bool?

Tags: ios, swift

I just learn swift 3.0 .I try to solve it but I couldn't. I have a func that check status and return true or false. but it always return value before Alamofire request finished and check my conditional.
Note: AlamoFire GET api request is work properly.

```
func check(_ id: int_fast64_t) ->  Bool { 

var status = false   

    Alamofire.request(urlCheckUpLicense, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if response.result.value != nil {
                print( "test...", response.result.value ?? "success")
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print( "type of Json = ", type(of: JSON))
                    if let dict = JSON as? NSDictionary {
                        sta = Int(dict.value(forKey: "status_code") as! int_fast64_t)
                        if sta == 200 {

                            status = true

                        }
                            else {

                            status = false

                        }

                    }

                }
            }

            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error ?? "Error")
            break
        }
       } 
    return status // it always return before Alamofire.request is finished.
}
```

Comment: look for **completion handler**, there are lots of Post already on SO similar to this.

Comment: AlamoFire GET api request is work properly. but I have problems with this function. it returns value before alamofire get api request had finished.

Comment: Alamofire.request... is async request, it executes in a background thread. Therefore   Alamofire.request(...) is just schedules the execution. You should use completion block and rewrite this function as async function

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know it executes in a background thread but I don't know how to schedules the execution.